# Facebook Login : How to set login callback for IOS app?

Tags: ios, facebook-graph-api, facebook-login

I integrated Facebook Login in my IOS App using Facebook SDK for IOS. It is working fine but I want to set callback url to my server address. I'm using swift for development. How can I achieve this?

AppDelegate.swift

```
func application(application: UIApplication, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions launchOptions: [NSObject: AnyObject]?) -> Bool {
        // Override point for customization after application launch.
        return FBSDKApplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(application, didFinishLaunchingWithOptions: launchOptions)
    }

   func application(application: UIApplication,
       openURL url: NSURL,
       sourceApplication: String?,
       annotation: AnyObject?) -> Bool {
           return FBSDKAplicationDelegate.sharedInstance().application(
               application,
               openURL: url,
               sourceApplication: sourceApplication,
               annotation: annotation)
   }
```